# How Can I simulate Packet Drop at QoS (Traffic control)

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, qos, vlan

I wanted to simulate a situation where  ping/icmp packet following through egress path should be dropped due to Linux QoS and these dropped packet should be captured by VLAN stats under ifconfig command.

I would want to trace down the code where packet drop counters is updated under vlan 802.1q code.I have identified vlan_dev.c file but for confirmation needed to simulate above scenario.